# How to set a Image to a Image View from a URL Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to download and show  a image in my imageview from URL that i will get dyncamically .I have tried this way

```
 URL url = new URL(parsedWeatherResponse.getWeatherIconUrl());
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            weather_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But it showing exception that is

```
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.itintestapp/com.example.itintestapp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at com.example.itintestapp.MainActivity.setSectorData(MainActivity.java:64)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at com.example.itintestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-04 12:22:40.221: E/AndroidRuntime(15097):    ... 11 more
```

Please help me how couuld i do this .I have show a image  from a URL

**I have tried this way**

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
    }
```

**Calling**

```
 new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weather_image))
            .execute(parsedWeatherResponse.getWeatherIconUrl());
```

Getting this **exception**

```
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at com.example.itintestapp.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:32)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at com.example.itintestapp.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-04 12:29:14.298: E/AndroidRuntime(15813):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Check Your InternetConnection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1318946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the network related operation on the ui thread. So, you get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You should use a `Thread` or `Asynctask`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Check the docs there is an example.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv ;
    ProgressDialog pd; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Downloading Image");
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             new DownloadImageTask(iv).execute("http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png");
        }

    });

}
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
          InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
          mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @Rahul included example with snapshot. try the example it should work

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which indicates that you're performing network operation on main thread, while it should be performed in other thread.

Follow this question for further information: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1):

As you are running Network Related work on `MainThread` i.e. `UIThread` which cause `UIThread` not to laid out it's `View`on Screen or `Activity`. That's according to `ThreadPolicy` all the time consuming and variable operation are need to performed on `AysncTask` or `Thread`.

As per below `LongOperation` is  `AsyncTask` which can be executed by calling `execute()` on it.

```
new LongOperation().execute();
```

---

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) 
      {
       try 
          {
          URL url = new URL(parsedWeatherResponse.getWeatherIconUrl());
          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
          } 
       catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       return bmp;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) 
      {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       weather_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
       }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly show image from web without downloading it. Please check the below function . It will show the images from the web into your image view.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then set image to imageview using code in your activity.

Comment: The exception you got is clearly saying that you cannot have a network operation on the UI thread. Have AsyncTask instead. Call this method in an AsyncTask. I just show the code inside doInBackground