# Image URL to bitmap

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

I am getting profile image from Facebook SDK, it returns me a `url`. When I open it in browser it shows the image. But when I convert it into bitmap, it returns null. Here is my code:

```
String id = user.getId();
try {
      URL image_path = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ id+ "/picture?type=large");
      Bitmap profPict = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_path.openConnection().getInputStream());
      System.out.println("profPict::> " + profPict);
      ImageView img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      img.setImageBitmap(profPict);
      System.out.println("image::> " + image_path);
}
catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use this link



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175133/how-to-set-a-image-to-a-image-view-from-a-url-android

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String srcurl){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the third party libraries available which will accept URL and the ImageView and will download and set the image in the ImageView.

[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is quite useful.